# "no ivar" on Xcode Instruments Leaks Cycles graph

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I am using instruments to check my app for leaks and I am trying to learn how to read the leaks cycles data.
I am getting this graph on one of my leaks:

[image]

What is the meaning if the graph ? What does it mean "no ivar"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "no ivar" message is similar to looking at the call stack of a program that has its symbols stripped. If you were looking at the call stack, you would see a memory address instead of the function name. In your example Instruments is showing the addresses, +16 and +24. Instruments can't find the variable name that allocated the memory so you get the [no ivar] message.

I don't have a solution to get Instruments to provide better information. I've never been able to get Instruments to do much with leak cycles.

UPDATE

If you're trying to find where your code leaks memory, I recommend switching to the call tree view, which you can do from the jump bar. Selecting the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes make it easier to locate your code in the call tree view. The checkboxes are on the left side of the trace document window.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to locate it other way

Comment: I got the same situation, the weird thing is, there's nothing in the Call Tree section

Comment: Did you have to do anything special to see the graph view?  I see no expanding triangles on the left, and the graph column is blank.

Comment: @chrisco Your app must have a leak cycle to have a graph column and the expanding triangles shown in the question's screenshot. If you have a memory leak but no leak cycle, there will be no expanding triangles and no graph.

Comment: Hmm.  I wonder if it suffices to say then that it won't catch leak cycles from closures.  Hopefully that is just a matter of work in progress.  For the record, I did have leak cycles from the use of self in a closure, but was trying to figure out how to find it with Instruments.

Comment: The "update" edit works a treat, you can double click the last element in the tree and it shows the readable source code where the issue starts.  Great stuff, found 6 leaks in my app this way.